# How to calculate correlation between two MLEs?

Tags: correlation, variance, maximum-likelihood, covariance

Let's say I have a dataset: $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ that follows some distribution $F(\theta)$. Assume that the MLE for $\theta$ does not have a closed form, so we must find it using numerical methods (Newton-Raphson, Fisher-Scoring, etc.).

Now, first consider the MLE based on the full dataset, call it $\hat{\theta}_n$. Next, assume that some of the data is removed, so that we are left with only the values $X_1, \ldots, X_{n-k}$ where $k < n$. The MLE can be found for this reduced data, call it $\hat{\theta}_{n-k}$.

I want to find the variance of the difference in these two MLEs:

$Var(\hat{\theta}_{n} - \hat{\theta}_{n-k})$ = $Var(\hat{\theta}_{n}) + Var(\hat{\theta}_{n-k}) - 2Cov(\hat{\theta}_{n}, \hat{\theta}_{n-k})$.

So essentially, how can I compute the covariance here? I do not want to consider bootstrap or resampling methods if possible.